# Responsive SVG text

Tags: html, svg

I have SVG text, which goes out of viewport because of its length, how to make it to the next line when there's too much content?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/nagshankar/pen/JjOwegd

HTML:

```
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">  
    <text x="0" y="100">
       Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
   </text> 
 </svg>
```

CSS:

```
svg{width:100%;height:100%}
text{font-size:5rem}
```

Comment: Use a viewBox attribute for the svg element. Try `viewBox="0 30 5000 100"`

Comment: @enxaneta that works only for the above content, what if there's still more content? i don't want to use viewbox, any alternate solution

Comment: In this case you may need to use javascript to get the text length (with getComputedTextLength) or you may consider using a foreignObject to put the text in

Answer (score 0):

You may help this

```
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <code>
            <text x="20" y="30" style="width:200px; font-size: 20px;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</text>
        </code>
    </svg>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: that doesn't work